# Attaching props on a stateless function from props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a React Component which takes in a component (`PropTypes.func` or `PropTypes.element`) through prop `component={MyTemplate}`, which will serve as a template, similar how `react-router` does route definitions.

Inside of the component I want to attach props to the `component` element. By the docs I understand that I sohuld be using `cloneElement` to attach props to it.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  // ...

  render () {
    const {component, blockProps} = this.props;
    const body = cloneElement(component, blockProps);

    return (
      <div className="sortable-block__body">
        {body}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// later when rendering the component
<MyComponent component={component} ... />
```

When rendering the component React throws Invariant Violation:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

Doesn't `cloneElement` consider stateless functions as an `ReactElement`?
If not, then how do I manage adding props the stateless component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `element` prop type expects an element, which will be like `<MyTemplate />` — i.e. with props. But you are accepting an element constructor (`MyTemplate`).

Also, to create an instance from constructor, you don't need `cloneElement`, use the JSX syntax instead (and capitalize the variable):

```
const Component = this.props.component;
const body = <Component {...blockProps} />
```

Comment: Had tried before `<component {...blockProps}/>` which didn't work. But if I assign the `component` to a variable named `Component` it works. Thanks for the help, didn't know the first letter capitalisation had such effect.

Comment: If it's not capitalized, React treats it as tag name, not a component